# Should I even check for a default value when calling IEnumerable<T>.FirstOrDefault where T: struct

Tags: c#

I have a sequence of `struct`s like so:

```
struct Foo { }

...

// somewhere else
var foos = GetListOfFoos();

...

// somewhere else
var foo = foos.FirstOrDefault();
```

Now, should I just go ahead and use the `foo` I just retrieved without worrying about nullability, of course because `structs` are not nullable since they're value types.

It just feels a bit worrying.

I know this is a stupid question and the answer is, "Yes, just use it without any checks for null." But I don't know why I am asking this even or what the question here is.

I am not missing anything by not checking for nullability here, right? There *cannot* be an invalid state for structs put inside that `IEnumerable<T>`, right?

Of course, I understand that if `Foo` had uninitialized members because it declared a parameterized ctor that did not initialize each and every member, one or more members of the instance of `Foo` will be in an unsable state. But as such each instance of `Foo` in that list will amount to something and there's no need to check for nulls or anything as there is no such thing as `default(Foo)`, right? Of course, just confirming.

Comment: Without seeing the declaration of `GetListOfFoos` I'm reluctant to giving you a guarantee, but if it does indeed return a `List<Foo>` then you're correct, `.GetFirstOrDefault` will either throw an exception or return a struct value, never null (in this case).

Comment: if `GetListOfFoos()` doesn't return any item, `FirstOrDefault()` will create an instance of `Foo` with all fields assigned to zeros (`0` for `int`, `0.0` for `double`, `false` for `bool`, `null` for any reference values etc.); no *unstable* (i.e. *trash*) states or values

Comment: There is a `default(Foo)` which is what `foo` will be if `foos` is empty. Your question really seems to be about how structs are default initialised.

Comment: @Lee That's strange because I get a compiler error when I check for `if (foo == default(Foo))`. The compiler says, "Operator == cannot be applied to operands of type Foo and Foo."

Comment: Yes that's because you haven't implemented `operator=` for `Foo`. You should be able to do `Foo f = default(Foo); foo.SomeMethod()`.

Comment: side note: *many times* (not all) when someone uses a `struct Foo` - they are doing so inappropriately. I know nothing at all about your scenario, and there are many *great cases* for `struct`; I use it myself quite often - but please please check you're using `struct` for the right reasons. Many unexpected behaviours are caused by ***inappropriate*** use of `struct`

Comment: @MarcGravell I am using the `struct` here as an immutable type to hold just a single string (received via ctor argument and held in a read-only auto property) and another private field derived from the single string argument.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 fair enough - that sounds perfectly legit. Just thought it was worth mentioning, as I've seen *so so many* mistakes from this :) sorry for any distraction :)

Comment: @Lee Ah, I see. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcGravell Not at all. Your input is very much appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if value types are not null you should worry about this value being the default value if that was exceptional or not expected.

> there is no such thing as default(Foo)

Sure, It will return an instance of this type where all members are nitialized to their default alues.

If you take f.e. `struct Guid` then `default(Guid)` returns an instance which is equal to `Guid.Empty` or `new Guid()`.

So my advice is, don't compare with `default(yourStruct)` because that could lead to nasty bugs if the default struct could be a valid instance. Instead you could use `Any`:

```
bool containsAny = foos.Any();
if(containsAny)
{
    Foo firstFoo = foos.First();
}
```

[MSDN: `default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions)

- returns `null` for reference types(class types and interface types)
- zero for numeric value types
- for user-defined structs, it returns the struct initialized to the zero bit pattern, which produces 0 or null for each member depending on whether that member is a value or reference type. For nullable value types, default returns a `System.Nullable<T>`, which is initialized like any struct.

Comment: You're saying `default(Foo)` is the state of `Foo` if `Foo` had no `ctors` at all, whether parameterized or parameterless and was thus initialized by the CLR by setting all its members to their default values?

Answer (score 1):

If `T` is a `struct`, you *can't* check for `null`: it will *never be* `null`, and a real "zero" (equivalent) in the list/sequence will be indistinguishable from "no there weren't any values in the list/sequence".

No, you don't need to check for `null` here.